# Function to behave differently on class vs on instance

Tags: python, function, class, methods, python-descriptors

I'd like a particular function to be callable as a classmethod, and to behave differently when it's called on an instance.

For example, if I have a `class Thing`, I want `Thing.get_other_thing()` to work, but also `thing = Thing(); thing.get_other_thing()` to behave differently.

I think overwriting the `get_other_thing` method on initialization should work (see below), but that seems a bit hacky.  Is there a better way?

```
class Thing:

    def __init__(self):
        self.get_other_thing = self._get_other_thing_inst()

    @classmethod
    def get_other_thing(cls):
        # do something...

    def _get_other_thing_inst(self):
        # do something else
```

Comment: Isn't this what we use inheritance for. Define a separate class with your new method - which inherits from parent class, then by scope, instance will return methods from it's class definition; if not found in its definition it will go to parent class.

Comment: @Poppinyoshi that's two different classes.  I could also create two different classes without inheritance to solve the problem... or I could create different functions in the same class and call them separately.  But that's not what I'm asking.

Comment: Descriptors pass whether or not they're on an instance, but that takes a bit more code.

Comment: I wrote an answer for this that I thought was cleaner than yours and then realized that it was just what you had done. I think what you have is cleaner than overriding `__getattribute__`, and I can't think of a better way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Great question! What you seek can be easily done using *descriptors*.

**[Descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html)** are Python objects which implement the *descriptor protocol*, usually starting with `__get__()`.

They exist, mostly, to be set as a class attribute on different classes. Upon accessing them, their `__get__()` method is called, with the instance and owner class passed in.

```
class DifferentFunc:
    """Deploys a different function accroding to attribute access

    I am a descriptor.
    """

    def __init__(self, clsfunc, instfunc):
        # Set our functions
        self.clsfunc = clsfunc
        self.instfunc = instfunc

    def __get__(self, inst, owner):
        # Accessed from class
        if inst is None:
            return self.clsfunc.__get__(None, owner)

        # Accessed from instance
        return self.instfunc.__get__(inst, owner)


class Test:
    @classmethod
    def _get_other_thing(cls):
        print("Accessed through class")

    def _get_other_thing_inst(inst):
        print("Accessed through instance")

    get_other_thing = DifferentFunc(_get_other_thing,
                                    _get_other_thing_inst)
```

And now for the result:

```
>>> Test.get_other_thing()
Accessed through class
>>> Test().get_other_thing()
Accessed through instance
```

That was easy!

By the way, did you notice me using `__get__` on the class and instance function? Guess what? Functions are also descriptors, and that's the way they work!

```
>>> def func(self):
...   pass
...
>>> func.__get__(object(), object)
<bound method func of <object object at 0x000000000046E100>>
```

Upon accessing a function attribute, it's `__get__` is called, and that's how you get function binding.

For more information, I highly suggest reading the [Python manual](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors) and the ["How-To"](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) linked above. Descriptors are one of Python's most powerful features and are barely even known.

---

### Why not set the function on instantiation?

Or **Why not set `self.func = self._func` inside `__init__`?**

Setting the function on instantiation comes with quite a few problems:

1. `self.func = self._func`causes a circular reference. The instance is stored inside the function object returned by `self._func`. This on the other hand is stored upon the instance during the assignment. The end result is that the instance references itself and will clean up in a much slower and heavier manner.
2. Other code interacting with your class might attempt to take the function straight out of the class, and use `__get__()`, which is the usual expected method, to bind it. They will receive the wrong function.
3. Will not work with `__slots__`.
4. Although with descriptors you need to understand the mechanism, setting it on `__init__` isn't as clean and requires setting multiple functions on `__init__`.
5. Takes more memory. Instead of storing one single function, you store a bound function for each and every instance.
6. Will not work with [properties](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property).

There are many more that I didn't add as the list goes on and on.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the details description and explanations!  Do you see any particular benefit to this approach over resetting the function on instantiation?

Comment: @DilithiumMatrix That's another good one! I really like your questions mate. Resetting the function on instantiation causes a circular reference, is unexpected when invoking `__get__` externally, doesn't behave as well with other code that expect the function to act normally and all sorts of other pitfalls.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a bit hacky solution:

```
class Thing(object):
    @staticmethod
    def get_other_thing():
        return 1

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if name == 'get_other_thing':
            return lambda: 2
        return super(Thing, self).__getattribute__(name)

print Thing.get_other_thing()  # 1
print Thing().get_other_thing()  # 2
```

If we are on class, staticmethod is executed. If we are on instance, `__getattribute__` is first to be executed, so we can return not `Thing.get_other_thing` but some other function (`lambda` in my case)

Comment: Ha, very hacky (and I think hackier than mine), but also very clever.  Thanks!